# Will observers automatically removed when observers become nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, observer-pattern

I'm uisng `addObserver:selector:name:object:` in `viewDidLoad`.

And I'm using `removeObserver:name:object:` in `viewWillDisappear:animated:` to remove observer.

What will happen if I failed to remove observer by passing wrong parameter to `removeObserver:name:object:`?
(For example, observer isn't removed if I pass wrong notification to parameter `name` or wrong object to `object` or `Observer`)

If the observer still not nil after calling `removeObserver:name:object:`, I can find out that removing observer failed because notificationSelector will being called.

But if the observer become nil after calling `removeObserver:name:object:`, I can not find out whether removing observer failed or not.

Will observers automatically removed when observer become nil?
Or does `notification dispatch table` of `NSNotificationCenter` became larger and larger and eventually the app become slow?

**EDIT**

When I use subclass of UIViewController object for observer, the app doesn't crash after ViewController's `dealloc` are called.
But when I use a object of other class, the app crashs after the object's `dealloc` are called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** From [`-[NotificationCenter removeObserver:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver?language=objc):

> If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its `dealloc` method. Otherwise, you should call this method or `removeObserver:name:object:` before observer or any object specified in `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` or `addObserver:selector:name:object:` is deallocated.

**Old answer:**

Observers are not removed automatically. From the NSNotificationCenter Class Reference:

> Important: The notification center does not retain its observers,
>   therefore, you must ensure that you unregister observers (using
>   removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object:) before they are
>   deallocated. (If you don't, you will generate a runtime error if the
>   center sends a message to a freed object.)

You should therefore call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

in your `dealloc` method if you are not 100% sure that the observer was not removed previously.

Comment: thanks. I found that if I use subclass of UIViewController as observer, runtime error doesn't happen. If I use object of other class as observer, runtime error happens. Perhaps, UIViewController calls `removeObserver:self` in its `dealloc`. But I don't know how to check if super class really removed observer.

Comment: I googled your quote from the (?) reference, but couldn't find it, so that's probably old information. Now it seems this is still correct at this point of time; NSNotificationCenter does not retain the observer, as I get dealloc called on an object without even removing it as observer. Now, of course the right thing would be to remove it in dealloc as per  this answer. Still the documentation does not state if the observer is retained or not and is thus a bit unclear IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put in the correct Observer for the Observer to be removed. If you pass the wrong parameter to name or object (or nil), the receiver will not use them as criteria for removal.

All Cocoa programs have a default NSNotificationCenter, so once you remove the observers you shouldn't have to worry about the it taking up more memory.